# Google Speech-to-Text: Invalid recognition 'config': bad sample rate hertz

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am trying to convert speech to text using the REST full service. I am using .wav file (PCM 16 bit Mono 16000 HZ)

URL: https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:recognize

JSON request:

```js
{
    "config": {
        "enableAutomaticPunctuation": "true",
        "encoding": "LINEAR16",
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "model": "default"
    },
    "audio": {
        "content": "QzpcU3BlZWNoVG9UZXh0XGVuZ2xpc2hcUENNXEVORy1DUk0tRE9XTlRJTUUud2F2"
    }
}
```

Error:

```js
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid recognition 'config': bad sample rate hertz.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Could you please help to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

The [API request](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol#make_an_audio_transcription_request) needs to specify a `sampleRateHertz`, which is the sample rate of the audio you sent, in Herz.

In your case, that's 16000, so your request should include:

```js
"config": {
    ...,
    "sampleRateHertz": 16000
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input now I am getting output as null

Comment: @Tarun, that's a different issue. The `audio` `content` is supposed to be the contents of your wav file, base64 encoded. Yours is the string `C:\SpeechToText\english\PCM\ENG-CRM-DOWNTIME.wav` base64 encoded.

Comment: Ok Thanks  but what can be the reason for output null

Comment: @Tarun, the reason for the null output is the fact that you did not send any input. You need to send the API some audio to analyze. You did not send it any audio. `audio` `content` needs to contain the base64 encoded **contents** of your wav file (the bytes from the file), not the **path** to the wav file.